# How do you pass a method to @Scheduled annotation in micronaut?

Tags: java, cron, scheduler, micronaut

I'm trying to pass a method to a @Scheduled annotation in micronaut

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay= "#{getDelay()}")
void scheduledJob() { ..<does some work>..}

String getDelay() { return config.getValue();}
```

This config returns a value from a database and needs to be a configurable value.

For now I am able to get this value from application.yml by passing

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = "${job.delay}")
```

Can't find any documentations for micronaut that enables me to do this.
Although I did find a way to do it for spring.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure that the feature that you are trying to use is supported at all, maybe it would be better to register the scheduler manually after reading the value from the db

Comment: I believe this is coming with Micronaut version 4.0.